# Forming a list of tuple from unequal length of elements inside a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with unequal length of values.

Example:

```
d= {'190': ['229'], '192': ['205'], '193': ['259'], '194': ['196', '204', '242', '249', '254', '266', '299', '302', '346'], '195': ['218', '273', '275', '306', '328'], '196': ['204', '249', '254', '266', '285', '330', '346'], '197': ['251', '272', '281', '284', '309', '320', '329'], '198': ['348', '351', '364', '393', '399', '441', '476', '501', '549', '564'], '199': ['200', '203', '211', '212', '222', '223', '231', '232', '238', '239', '252', '261', '265', '271', '288', '291', '298', '304', '313', '314', '315', '322', '324', '325', '342'], '200': ['203', '223', '224', '232', '236', '239', '248', '252', '271', '274', '276', '277', '280', '285', '297', '304', '322', '323', '324', '325', '332', '334'], '201': ['259'], '202': ['329'], '203': ['211', '223', '238', '239', '261', '265', '268', '270', '271', '272']}
```

I want to create list of tuples of these values inside dictionary

example code I used to create that is:

```
for k, v in d.items():
    #print(list(zip(v[::1], v[1::2])))

    if len(v) == 5:
        it = iter(v)
        print(len(v))
        print(v)
        print(list(zip(it, it)))
```

which yields

```
['218', '273', '275', '306', '328']
[('218', '273'), ('275', '306')]
```

But I ideally wanted is:

```
[('218', '273'), ('273', '275'), ('275', '306'), ('306', '328')]
```

What am I missing with this iteration? I used that as an illustration, but I want to be able have dictionary values with `len(v)==1`, for an instance `'190': ['229']`  that results to `('229',)` as well. If `len(v)==1` is hard to implement, I am fine `len(v)>1` advise.

Comment: You should not use the same iterator here twice. You can work with `islice` from itertools, and use `list(zip(v, islice(v, 1, None))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems what you are asking for:

for all cases

comprehension:

```
result = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    indexes = [i for i, b in enumerate(v)]
    result[k] = [(v[i], v[i + 1]) for i in indexes[:-1]] if len(v) > 1 else [(v[0],)]

print(result)
```

or just if - else:

```
result = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    indexes = [i for i, b in enumerate(v)]
    if len(v) > 1:
        result[k] = [(v[i], v[i + 1]) for i in indexes[:-1]]
    else:
        result[k] = [(v[0],)]

print(result)
```

for your case(==5):

```
result = {}

for k, v in d.items():
    indexes = [i for i, b in enumerate(v)]
    if len(v) == 5:
        result[k] = [(v[i], v[i + 1]) for i in indexes[:-1]]

print(result)
```

Comment: I was playing with enumerate, this solves the problem. Thanks apet!

Answer (score 0):

You use the same iterator twice, hence that means every value in the original list is yielded once.

You can for example work with `islice` of `itertools`, to refer both to the list, and its "tail". In the case the length of the list is one, it is probably the simplest to wrap that value in a singleton tuple:

```
from itertools import islice

for k, v in d.items():
    if len(v) > 1:
        print(list(zip(it, islice(v, 1, None))))
    elif len(v) == 1:
        print([(v[0],)])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way you can achieve that with less code:

```
tuples_list = [] #The list where we are going to save the tuples

#We iterate the values and we convert each list into a tuple
for sublist in d.values():
    tuples_list.append(tuple(sublist))
```

This way you don't need to worry about the len of each list. You can convert a list into a tuple without any problem.